# Pimcore Exam: what are the options for creating dynamic routes for data object detail pages?

Tags: pimcore

I've got a question for pimcore. What are the possibilities to make dynamic routes for e.g. for an object detail page?

In my opinion I can achieve this with Custom Routes/Static Routes and the Symfony Routes, right?

At the moment I stuck at the exam course and the above answers are incorrect.

The question is: what are the options for creating dynamic routes for data object detail pages?

1. Smyfony Routes
2. Url Slugs for Data Objects
3. Pretty Urls
4. Static Routes

I've tried so many variations and all are wrong.

I've read through the documentation and the pimcore own community. I think the expected answers are wrong. For me it is important to understand what is right and why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be

- Smyfony Routes
- Url Slugs for Data Objects
- Static Routes